# Laundry Utility Sink Won't Work

Tags: faucet, sink

I replaced my old builder's grade utility sink with a standard Lowes cabinet sink combo. After installing I have problems with the water flow. If you turn the water (hot or cold) on fast it will not flow. If you turn them on slowly it works just fine. Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'll guess that there's an issue with the faucet washers coming loose, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Did you change the flexible supply lines to the faucet? If so, did you use the special ones with a valve to prevent flooding in case of a rupture? I think one brand is called "FloodSafe".

Comment: Jim make that an answer I was thinking the same.+